# How admin can search through all users for a attribute in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

[User structure in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGB9h.png)

I made an app in swift 3 where registration request from user is manually approved or rejected by the admin. Is there a way that whenever a new user registers, me as an admin can get some kind of notification like an email etc.

When a user sends a registration request, all user info is stored in firebase with “UserRegisteration” attribute to be zero which means user is not approved. Admin has to manually change “UserRegisteration” to 1 which means that registration request from user is now approved. But Admin has to manually check every user which is not an efficient approach. Is there any possibility where I can search the users with “UserStatus” attribute 0 so that I don’t have to check each user. I tried Looking into Admin SDK of firebase but it looks like that as of now for swift admin SDK is not available. I have attached a image which contains the structure that I have in Firebase. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: So if I understand right, you have additional node in Firebase where you hold information about user? Can you provide an example so we can see users structure?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just added a image which contains the user structure that I have in Firebase

Comment: Still can't see whole structure, there is "UsersStatus" missing. Anyway this should help you get all the users that still aren't approved: `ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "UsersStatus").queryEqual(toValue: 0).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
})` Just replace with your data if I didn't insert right. Also, I would recommend you to remove user's `password` from database. Why do you need that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are absolutely right, there is no need to store user password.

Comment: My mistake, attribute is actually "UserRegisteration" which is by default 0 when user send the request and then admin has to make it 1 which means user registration request is approved. The code you wrote seems to solve the issue but I am still confused where I actually have to do that like where in Firebase because swift app has nothing to do with admin controls.

Comment: So I would like to do this user administration in the firebase itself.For example as I get a new user registerers , me being an admin get a notification email and then I go to firebase, query the data to check all users for the attribute "UserRegisteration" and then I can get all users with "UserRegisteration" as 0 which means that they are new users. Right now I have to expand each user and check it manually

Comment: For administration you should create a separate part to manage users: like a web app or a locked part inside your iOS app that can only be accessed by administrators. For notifications, check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ which will help you with sending push notifications to your device.